# ng-model convert object to string

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Being very new to Angular I have a kinda unusual request.

I have a bunch of input fields

```
<div class="blurb" ng:repeat="item in fieldData.postData">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.key" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.operator" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.value" />
        </div>
```

The values of these fields inturn are bound to another field

```
<input name="finalVal" type="text" ng-model="fieldData.postData" />
```

All works fine and I get an object inside finalVal, but I want the object in string format. Is there a way to achieve it without any changes in my controller? The reason being finalVal is basically stored as a string in DB and I cannot modify the data type.

Appreciate the help

Comment: in angularjs or javascript ineger and string are same its var, you just need to store it in db no need to convert as string

Comment: `fieldData.postData` is an array and that's why you are able to iterate through it using `ng-repeat`. Definitely it's a `object` which might become `"fieldData.postData"` if converted to string. Is that what you want?

Comment: The thing is, fieldData.postData when gets bound to finalVal, I want to convert it to string? i tried using ng-value instead of ng-model and a few other options but  nothing worked. I could do it in controller but need to make sure there isnt a way to do it at the view level.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Yes thats what i want. To convert               fieldData.postData to "fieldData.postData"

Comment: __I get an object inside finalVal__

Comment: Thats correct I want to know if there is a way to convert it into string in the view and not on controller